# A condition like primeness for zero ideal

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $D$ be an integral domain (zero ideal is prime). Then for
every nonzero element $a,b \in D$, we have $\langle a\rangle\cap \langle b\rangle\neq 0$.

Now in a general case, let $R$ be a commutative ring with 1, such
that $R$ has no nontrivial idempotent. I am looking for a
general condition (other that $0$ is an irreducible ideal)  for $0$
(the zero ideal) under which $\langle a\rangle\cap \langle b\rangle\neq 0$ for all nonzero
element $a,b \in R$.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1687381/a-relation-between-the-intersection-of-two-nonzero-principal-ideals-and-the-zero

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer:
It is easy to see that "for all nonzero elements $a$ and $b$, one has $\langle a\rangle\cap \langle b\rangle\neq 0$ **iff** for all nonzero ideals $I$ and $J$, has $I\cap J\neq 0.$" For Artinian local rings this is equivalent to saying that ring is *Gorenstein*; see *Bruns_Herzog* Exercise 3.2.15.